# Is there a way to perform lag operation in R using sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

Is there a way to do the below operation in SQL. I mean using sqldf package in R

```
asdff <- data.frame(a=c(1,3,3,45))
asdff$b <- c(NA,asdff$a[-nrow(asdff)])
   a  b
1  1 NA
2  3  1
3  3  3
4 45  3
```

Comment: what is the above operation? can you please explain it?

Comment: ````asdff$b <- c(NA,asdff$a[-nrow(asdff)])```` is actually duplicating column "a" from 2nd row.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these will lag the `a` column:

```
sqldf("select a, lag(a) over () as b from asdff")

sqldf("select a, lag(a) over (order by rowid) as b from asdff")

sqldf("select x.a, y.a as b 
  from asdff x 
  left join asdff y on x.rowid = y.rowid + 1")
```

If the data has a column that corresponds to times then that can be used and allow lagging with respect to the times even if the data frame is not already ordered by those times. With the built in `BOD` data frame (that has `Time` and `demand` columns)

```
sqldf("select *, lag(demand) over (order by Time) as prev from BOD")
```

For more information see: https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html